# Fetch call data not going through

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

I am having trouble with a fetch call. The post data does not appear to be available in the endpoint when I use my client side app. With Postman, the route works fine.

Here is the post action, where the data originates:

```
export const createBoard = (name, user_id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const authToken = getState().authToken; 
    console.log(`IN ACTION: ${name}${user_id}`)
    return fetch('http://localhost:8080/board/', {
        method: 'POST', 
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, user_id })
    })
    .then(res => normalizeResponseErrors(res))
    .then(res => {return res.json()})
    .then(board => dispatch(addToBoards(board)))
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err); 
    });
}
```

Here is the endpoint. The "name" and "user_id" data do not come through:

```
// CREATE NEW BOARD
router.post('/', jsonParser, jwtAuth, (req, res) => {
    console.log(`IN ENDPOINT: ${req.body.name}${req.body.user_id}`)
    return Board
        .create({ 
            name: req.body.name, 
            user_id: req.body.user_id 
        })
        .then(board => {
            res.status(201).json({ board })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.sendStatus(500); 
        }); 
});
```

Again, the endpoint works with Postman, so I think I did something wrong in the fetch block, but I can't see what. Help!

Here is the error:

```
IN ENDPOINT: undefinedundefined
{ SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: Board.name cannot be null,
notNull Violation: Board.user_id cannot be null
```

Comment: Your endpoint url is "/" however on the client side you are using ''http://localhost:8080/board''.

Comment: I just caught that, and unfortunately, that's not the issue ha

Comment: It IS hitting the endpoint, it just isn't getting the data. I see the log on the other side.

Comment: Try sending the Content-Type header also. Postman would do it automatically. It might be considering the request body as plaintext.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!